# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compiler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_estimator.py in <module>()
     38 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_config
     39 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_context
---> 40 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_feed
     41 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import training_loop
     42 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import util as util_lib

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\tpu\tpu_feed.py in <module>()
     26 from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
     27 
---> 28 from tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental.xla_sharding import xla_sharding
     29 from tensorflow.compiler.xla.python_api import xla_shape
     30 from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.ops import tpu_ops

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compiler'
```

The above error occurred when I ran the following code:
env:windows10+jupyter notebook+tensorflow1.9+python3.6

```
import tensorflow as tf
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,24,24,3])
h_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x_image, 64,5,1, "SAME", 
activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your expected behaviour? It's not that unclear as in other questions. But better be explicit to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: This sounds like an environment gone awry during updates. What happens if you reinstall TensorFlow?

Comment: I can not call the method "tf.contrib.layers.conv2d"The above error occurred when I call it

Comment: It's not work when I reinstall the TensorFlow.the errors "No module named tensorflow.compiler" orrurs when I call method tf.contrib.layers.conv2d

Comment: It will be ok when I call then method tf.nn.conv2d

Comment: I ran your example using Python 3 on a Cloud TPU (ctpu) machine, defining `x` and initializing global variables as follows:

`sess = tf.Session(); sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()); x = tf.ones(shape=[24*24*3*50], dtype=tf.float32); x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,24,24,3]); h_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x_image, 64,5,1, "SAME", 
activation_fn=tf.nn.relu); sess.run(h_conv1)
`

This seemed to work without trouble. Same for you?

Comment: Thank you,Maybe there are some problems in jupyter.It works in pycharm

Comment: Ok. I moved my comment to an answer, given your confirmation that it's not tensorflow- or TPU-specific.

Comment: Also worth mentioning tf-trt its not supported on windows 10 https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-converting-tensorflow-model-to-tensorrt-on-windows-10/83892

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen if the installation of Tensorflow is incomplete (for example if "pip install tensorflow" has been interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your example using Python 3 on a Cloud TPU (ctpu) machine, defining `x` and initializing global variables as follows:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
x = tf.ones(shape=[24*24*3*50], dtype=tf.float32)
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,24,24,3])
h_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x_image, 64,5,1, "SAME",
                                   activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
sess.run(h_conv1)
```

and it worked correctly.